# I'd like @report_for to stick around for an entire session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

1. I created a method called "report4" in my application_controller which is used to set my "@report_for" variable
2. in another controller, "report4" is called with a before_filter for a view
3. In the view it displays as part of the heading
4. I thought that it would still be present when data is sent back to the controller for an update, but "@report_for" is coming up nil.

Can, and should, a variable like "@report_for" be set to exist for the entire session like "current_user"?

If not, is the best way to send it back in a hidden field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use the session hash (ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash):

```
session[:report_for] = 'whatever'
if session[:report_for].present?
  #do your thing
else
  #carry on
end
```